# Difference between two zero-one indicator functions

Tags: functions

I have a zero-one indicator function $I(cond)$ which returns $1$ if the condition *cond* is true and $0$ if *cond* is false.

Now I have the following difference: $I(a = c) - I(b = c)$. For some reason, I would like to write this difference as a function of $I(a \neq b)$ (and eventually other parameters). That is, I would like the term $I(a \neq b)$ to appear in the formula.

I came up to the following, but I am not sure if it is equal to $I(a = c) - I(b = c)$:
$$I(a=c)-I(b=c) = I(a \neq b)  *  ( I(a=c)-I(a \neq c) ) = I(a \neq b)  *  ( I(b \neq c)-I(b=c) )$$

EDIT: To reformulate the question differently:

Given that $I(a=c)−I(b=c)=I(a \neq b) \times F(a,b,c)$. I want to determine $F(a,b,c)$ such that $F(a,b,c)$ is not a function of $I(a \neq b)$ nor a function of $I(a=b)$, and $F(a,b,c)$ is written differently than just the trivial compact expression: $F(a,b,c)=I(a=c)−I(b=c)$

Comment: Knowing the *condition truth* of $a\neq b$ doesn't allow us to determine a value for $I(a=c) - I(b=c)$.  While $a=b$ implies that $I(a=c) - I(b=c)$ is zero, the converse is not true (both $a=c$ and $b=c$ can be false without implying $a=b$) and in any case $a\neq b$ cannot give a sign for $I(a=c) - I(b=c)$ in those cases where it is not zero.

Comment: @hardmath who said that the expression that I am looking for should only be based on the truth of $a \neq b$ ? Of course other terms like $I(a=c)$ and $I(b=c)$ should also appear in the expression. What I asked for is just to re-write $I(a=c)−I(b=c)$ so that $I(a \neq b)$ also appears in the expression.

Comment: @hardmath Let me reformulate the question differently: Given that $I(a=c)−I(b=c) = I(a \neq b) \times F(a, b, c)$. How to determine $F(a, b, c)$ if we assume that it is not a function of $I(a \neq b)$ nor a function of $I(a = b)$. Does it make sens now ?

If this is not possible, then I would have the same question for $I(a=c)−I(b=c) = I(a \neq b) + F(a, b, c)$.

Comment: @hardmath I want $F(a,b,c)$ to be written in a different manner than just the trivial $F(a,b,c)=I(a=c)−I(b=c)$

Comment: @hardmath I want $F(a,b,c)$ to be written in a different manner than just the trivial $F(a,b,c)=I(a=c)−I(b=c)$. For example, is it correct to write: $I(a=c)-I(b=c) = I(a \neq b)  *  ( I(a=c)-I(a \neq c) ) = I(a \neq b)  *  ( I(b \neq c)-I(b=c) )$ ?

Comment: @hardmath Right, it seems what I have proposed works only when $c \in {a, b}$. Do you have another solution for my problem then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was noted in the Comments on the Question, besides the case $a=b$, there is the case when $c$ is not equal to either $a$ or $b$ that implies:

$$ I(a=c) - I(b=c) = 0 $$

Therefore we can "factor out" this zero and express the formula $I(a=c) - I(b=c)$ as a multiple of both:

- $I(a\neq b)$, which results in zero whenever $a=b$, and
- $I((a-c)(b-c)=0)$, which results in zero whenever $c$ is neither $a$ nor $b$.

This reduces the "logical requirement" to only cases where $a\neq b$ and $c \in \{a,b\}$, for which you already see some solutions.  In particular:

$$ I(a=c) - I(b=c) = I(a\neq b)\cdot I((a-c)(b-c)=0)\cdot (1 - 2I(b=c)) $$

That is, excluding the cases already proscribed as giving a zero result, the third and final factor in this right hand side gives $1$ when $a=c$ and $b\neq c$ and gives $-1$ when $a\neq c$ and $b=c$.

The Reader may enjoy finding alternative forms of conditions that give equivalent indicator functions to the ones above.  For example:

$$ I((a-c)(b-c)=0) = I(a=c\; \lor \; b=c) $$